# Flask-Login Which Class's user is active

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

Hello I have Two classes User and ProductOwner 
They can be both logged in by Flask-Login
But when you are logged in and the browser revisits the ('/') page I can not redirect them to the user or Productowner page because I don't know the logged in user .if it belongs to User class or ProductOwner class. I think it is using cookie for logging in automatically.

At first I tought it would run @lm.user_loader at each loading. But it seems like it is not.

```
@lm.user_loader
def load_user(id):
    if id[0] == "u":
        session['current']='u'
        return User.query.get(int(id[1:]))
    if id[0] == "b":
        session['current']='b'
        return ProductOwner.query.get(int(id[1:]))
```

I think it is not running above code if you are revisiting the page without being logged out.
Because as far as I understood

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    if current_user.is_authenticated():
        if session['current']=='b':
            return render_template('b_loggedin.html')
        elif session['current']=='u':
            return render_template('userloggedin.html')
    return render_template('index.html')
```

returns index.html

Thank you

Comment: What are the implementations of User and ProductOwner classes? To be specific what is the code of `is_authenticated` method in those classes?

Comment: I did not write is_authenticated in those classes. Should I write ? I am still learning so I don't know what to do a lot. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As a short answer inherit your `User` and `ProductOwner` from `flask.ext.login.UserMixin`, read more [here](https://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#user-object-helpers).

But if you like to have a better code you need to make in dynamic. Relying on parts of your id to recognize user type and on another part as user ID is a bad practice and will make you more troubles in future.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Mehdi. I solved my problem by using is_authenticated method as Mehdi stated.I added code inside is_authenticated method.

Thank you very much.